# Pycharm 3rd party with different venv

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm, python-venv

Suppose I develop some application in data-science (ML). I keep project in pycharm with customized venv.

Now I need to link to project some 3rd party ML model packaged in pkl file. The problem that this model was constructed with some old versions of packages ( to be particular scikit-learn, scipy, numpy are much older there than I use in the project ). So when I connected model - I couldn't run in since versions of package in my proj and this one are different.

Seems like I need to use simultaneously 2 venv - one for running my project and another for running 3rd party model. Is that possible or how that problem could be solved else?

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

PyCharm supports multiple Python environments and you can manually change them using the selector at the bottom right. You can have any number of virtual environments here.

[image]

Alternative, don't use PyCharm to execute any Python code, but set up command line scripts that you execute from PyCharm Terminal for any tasks that need to have non-default virtual environment.